# How to create a command line to get a savefile?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        // no command-line arguments supplied
    } else {
        // args[0] contains the first command-line argument
    }
    // …
}
```

I know this is the way to set up the command line, but how do I make it select a file my program has made and open it up?

Comment: when you run the java program using command prompt, `java yourProgramName hi hello`, `hi` is passed as `arg[0]`, `hello` is passed as `arg[1]` and so on...

Comment: Combine that http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html with the response of vicky96 and you'll get it

Comment: Put the file path in `args[0]`

Comment: What are you struggling with? Getting the file from `args`, creating a `File`, opening a `File`, or even something else?

Comment: In addition to what everyone already said, you might want to get a path that contains a space in the middle, Let s say you want `Desktop\foo bar.txt`. you can write it like that: `java yourProgramName "Desktop\foo bar.txt" `. this way you get the full path where `java yourProgramName Desktop\foo bar.txt` will get you two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you would pass in the arguments "apple pie" `args[0]` would be apple and `args[1]` would be pie.

Now all you need to do is use that argument to provide a file path to a [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object.

```
File file = new File(args[0]);
```

If you need more then one file you can use a loop,

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

for(int i = 0; i > args.length; i++)
{
   files.add(new File(args[i]));
}
```

*Side note: Its a good idea to check if the file you provided exists, for this use the* `File.exists` *method.*